# listar resultados mysqli con etiqueta optgroup dentro de un select

Tags: php, html

Lo que necesito es listar las opciones segun la categoria a la que pertenecen, por eso la peticion sql ordena los productos por su categoria. Mi idea era que para el primer producto de cada categoria, abra un optgroup y cierre el anterior.

Codigo PHP

```
$anilloC = $collarC = $aroC = 0;
function getProducts($link){
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY Categoria ASC";
    if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)){
        if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
            $mysqli_result = $stmt->get_result();
            foreach($mysqli_result as $row) {
                if($row["Categoria"] = "Anillo" && $anilloC = 0){
                    echo '<optgroup label="Anillo">';
                    $anilloC = 1;
                }
                elseif($row["Categoria"] == "Collar" && $collarC = 0) {
                    echo '</optgroup>';
                    echo '<optgroup label="Anillo">';
                    $collarC = 1;
                }
                elseif($row["Categoria"] == "Aros" && $aroC = 0) {
                    echo '</optgroup>';
                    echo '<optgroup label="Aros">';
                    $aroC = 1;
                }
                echo '<option value="'. $row["id"] . '">'. $row["name"] . '</option>';
                }
                echo '</optgroup>';
            }
        }
    }
```

Base de datos "products"
[image: Imagen]

Codigo html resultante:

```
<select name="select">
                <option value="Select">Select</option>
                <option value="1">Anillo 1</option>
                <option value="2">Anillo 2</option>
                <option value="3">Anillo 3</option>
                <option value="4">Anillo 4</option>
                <option value="5">Anillo 5</option>
                <option value="6">Anillo 6</option>
                <option value="7">Anillo 7</option>
                <option value="13">Aros 1</option>
                <option value="8">collar 1</option>
                <option value="9">collar 2</option>
                <option value="10">collar 3</option>   
</select>
```

Por alguna razon los optgroup no se muestran dentro del select

Comment: ¿Podrías mostrarnos lo que arroja esto: `var_dump($mysqli_result);`

Comment: `object(mysqli_result)#3 (5) {
  ["current_field"]=>
  int(0)
  ["field_count"]=>
  int(6)
  ["lengths"]=>
  NULL
  ["num_rows"]=>
  int(11)
  ["type"]=>
  int(0)
}`

Comment: A ver, entonces puede que falte contexto en tu código. Pon un `var_dump($row);` dentro del bucle y muéstranos un par de resultados.

Comment: Analizando más a fondo, veo dos cosas sospechosas: 1º. La variables no están dentro del contexto de la función: `$anilloC = $collarC = $aroC = 0;` considero que deberías meterlas dentro. 2º. En el primer `if` tú estás haciendo una asingación con `=` no una comparación, que deber ser con `==`  o con `===`  (estricta).

Comment: Asi es, como se menciona en la respuesta por @triby el punto uno y dos se ha modificado y solucionado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Veo varios problemas:

1. Defines variables fuera de la función y no las estás agregando ni como parámetro ni con `global`, por lo que obtendrías un error al tratar de acceder a ellas.
2. La comparación se hace con dos signos igual, pero tienes `if($row["Categoria"] = "Anillo" && $anilloC = 0)`, donde asignas nuevo valor a `$row["Categoria"]` y cero a `$anilloC` en lugar de comparar su valor.
3. Siempre cierras `optgroup` en cada iteración del ciclo, sin importar si hay elementos internos o no.

**Posible solución:** Crear una variable para analizar la última categoría mostrada, si es diferente de la actual, crear el grupo y, de ser necesario, cerrar el anterior:

```
function getProducts($link){
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY Categoria ASC";
    if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)){
        if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
            $mysqli_result = $stmt->get_result();
            // Crear variable antes de entrar al ciclo
            $lastCat = '';
            foreach($mysqli_result as $row) {
                // Si la categoría actual es diferente de la anterior
                if($row['Categoria'] != $lastCat) {
                    // ¿Se debe cerrar el grupo?
                    if($lastCat != '') {
                        // Solo si no es la primera
                        echo '</optgroup>';
                    }
                    // Crear grupo para esta categoría
                    echo "<optgroup label=\"{$row['Categoria']}\">";
                    // Actualizar última categoría mostrada
                    $lastCat = $row['Categoria'];
                }
                // Agregar opción actual
                echo "<option value=\"{$row['id']}\">{$row['name']}</option>";
            }
            // Al salir del ciclo, cerrar grupo, solo si se creó alguno
            if($lastCat != '') {
                echo '</optgroup>';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Esto te permitiría agregar más categorías sin tener que agregar condicionales para cada una, reduciendo y optimizando el proceso.

Comment: El primer y segundo punto estas en lo correcto, lo he modificado y se ha solucionado y por ahora funciona con las 3 categorias definidas, pero claro, al intenar profundizar mas y codificar para cualquier numero de categorias suponiendo que se agregan mas en el futuro, mi codigo no es lo optimo. He proabdo tu codigo, pero me crea un optgroup por cada option.

Comment: @MartinSeguel, seguramente lo copiaste antes de que lo editara, me faltaba actualizar la variable `$lastCat`, revisa esa parte en la respuesta.

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo, ahora funciona bien :)